# x86 Windows is not currently supported by the .NET Core debugger. Debugging will not be available

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I can't debug my code. This is demo:

[x86 Windows is not currently supported by the .NET Core debugger. Debugging will not be available.][1]

This is a copy of launch.json:

```
`{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [

        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/Mega_01.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            // For more information about the 'console' field, see https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#console-terminal-window
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a copy of tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Mega_01.csproj"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

`  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKc9f.png

How to solve this problem without installing visual studio! Thanks!

Comment: are you using a 32bit version of windows?

Comment: Such a Exception message when trying to Debugg a x32 application on a x64 System is a know issue: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1716 Apparently they are phasing out x32 support with .NET Core and this debugger is simply a early sign.

Comment: Are there another ways to develop C# without installing Visual Studio???